# Xamarin Forms Camera wont display

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been using the Camera Application for a while, but today for some reason today its erroring out ?

The code being called is

```
    private async Task TakePictureAsync()
    {
        var photoResult = await cameraProvider.TakePictureAsync();

        if (photoResult != null)
        {
            Picture = photoResult.Picture;
        }
    }
```

When

```
    await cameraProvider.TakePictureAsync();
```

is called I get the error:-

```
2017-01-20 14:30:33.700 CameraApplicationiOS[235:9976] critical: 
Native stacktrace:
2017-01-20 14:30:33.841 CameraApplicationiOS[235:9976] critical:    0   CameraApplicationiOS                0x0000000100047d90 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 260
2017-01-20 14:30:33.841 CameraApplicationiOS[235:9976] critical:    1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x000000018353d348 _sigtramp + 52
2017-01-20 14:30:33.841 CameraApplicationiOS[235:9976] critical:    2   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x000000018347649c <redacted> + 100
2017-01-20 14:30:33.841 CameraApplicationiOS[235:9976] critical:    3   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x00000001834764c8 system_set_sfi_window + 0
2017-01-20 14:30:33.841 CameraApplicationiOS[235:9976] critical:    4   TCC                                 0x00000001866ea328 <redacted> + 0
2017-01-20 14:30:33.842 CameraApplicationiOS[235:9976] critical:    5   TCC                                 0x00000001866ea224 <redacted> + 0
2017-01-20 14:30:33.842 CameraApplicationiOS[235:9976] critical:    6   TCC                                 0x00000001866ed330 <redacted> + 348
2017-01-20 14:30:33.842 CameraApplicationiOS[235:9976] critical:    7   libxpc.dylib                        0x000000018357efcc <redacted> + 80
2017-01-20 14:30:33.842 CameraApplicationiOS[235:9976] critical:    8   libxpc.dylib                        0x000000018357ef3c <redacted> + 40
2017-01-20 14:30:33.843 CameraApplicationiOS[235:9976] critical:    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001833361bc <redacted> + 16
2017-01-20 14:30:33.844 CameraApplicationiOS[235:9976] critical:    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000183344a4c <redacted> + 732
2017-01-20 14:30:33.844 CameraApplicationiOS[235:9976] critical:    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018334634c <redacted> + 572
2017-01-20 14:30:33.844 CameraApplicationiOS[235:9976] critical:    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001833460ac <redacted> + 124
2017-01-20 14:30:33.844 CameraApplicationiOS[235:9976] critical:    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018353f2a0 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
2017-01-20 14:30:33.844 CameraApplicationiOS[235:9976] critical:    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018353ed8c start_wqthread + 4
2017-01-20 14:30:33.844 CameraApplicationiOS[235:9976] critical: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
==============
```

Comment: Have you set up your permissions?

Comment: Might be by design for missing [Privacy Keys](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction-to-ios10/security-privacy-enhancements/#Accessing_Private_User_Data) required by iOS 10. Check the crash logs for "__CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__". [Xamarin.iOS 10 release notes known issues](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_10/xamarin.ios_10.0/#Known_Issues).